# Why we used "this" keyword in this snippet?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, this, code-snippets

```
    var someObject = {
someArray : new Array(),

someInt : 0,

Total: function(){

this.someInt = 0;//we used "this" keyword here, why?Cant we just say "someInt = 0"?

for(var i=0;i<this.someArray.length;i++){//and here..

var c = this.someArray[i];//again we use "this"

this.someInt += c.value;//also here
}
```

so why did we use "this" keyword? cant we just type the name of the variable?

Comment: The someInt was declared before but yes, someInt could probably be used as a /var (also, pointing out that this.someInt has no effect in this particular snippet so it could be removed enitirely)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` keyword refers to the object on whose behalf the call is made later on, i.e. if you call the function like this:

```
someObject.Total()
```

then `this` will refer to `someObject` inside the function. Thanks to `this` keyword the function can modify `someInt` and read from `someArray` which are members of `someObject`. If you dropped `this` from the function body, all those references would be to global variables or variables local to the function body.

Answer (score 3):

No, the statement `someInt = 0` would not modify the `someInt` *property* of `someObject`. Instead, it would modify a property named `someInt` on the global/default object (`window` in a browser), which is obviously not want you want.

Note that (depending on how you intend to invoke the `Total` function) you could also write this as `someObject.someInt`. However, when calling the function like this:

```
someObject.Total()
```

...the value of `this` in the function is equal to `someObject`.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the variable is not fully created. By using the 'this' keyword you can access a variable from itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it's just for clarity. Always using `this.` is probably a good practice when you don't use special naming conventions for instance variables vs. local variables (in other languages as well, not just javascript).

Even though it may not be required in this case, if you had a larger function, with lots of local and instance variables, it makes things much clearer when you distinguish.

Comment: To answer the other question: No, we cannot "just type the name of the variable", because the variable would then not be defined as a property of `someObject`, but as a local (if using `var`) or global variable.

Comment: Right, this isn't "just for clarity".

Comment: Yep, I spoke too soon - the `this` is required in this case - I'm thinking in C#/Java, where something like this would be more of a preference/readability thing.

Comment: Feel free to downvote my answer - I feel guilty now for getting this wrong and getting upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Douglas Crockford in his `Javascript The Good Parts`, suggests not using this keywords in the code, for the functions from the object may be applied to other objects and this may cause errors. so it's better sometimes to use just variable names.

Comment: it isn't better to just use the variable names. Douglas Crockford says to assign "this" to "that", and use "that" instead of "this". This way when the method is called from the context of another object, "that" will refer to the original context and not the calling one. I hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

`someInt` is defined as a property of `someObject`.  It would need to be defined as a variable in order to access it that way.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7mSK/

Answer (score 0):

Understand `this` keyword in detail [HERE](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/)